# Using service to interface API endpoints in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, api, frontend

In the struggle to separate code in big scale applications, I have implemented an angular boilerplate. Seen as am I haven't had as much experience with Angular as I have with other Javascript frameworks I would like some input on this method.

When working with endpoints things can get really messy and code starts to get repeated ESP with AngularJs. Working on other people's projects I was sick of seeing...

```
$http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: '/posts'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  // code
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  // code
});
```

So I build a component which basically interfaces the http component but apply our current restful standards in place (handling http status correctly), scopes, local storage ect, combined with a method of implementing services for endpoint interfaces that strictly describe endpoints and how they will fit in with the application.

```
angular.module('Ripple').service('postModel', [function() {

'use strict';

return {

    /**
     * Rest Endpoint interface
     * @type {Object}
     */
    _rest: {
        getPosts: {
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/posts',
            method: 'GET',
            scopeUpdate: 'posts',
            localStorage: false,
            params: {
                // Endpoint params
            }
        },
        getPost: {
            url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/',
            method: 'GET',
            scopeUpdate: 'post',
            localStorage: false,
            pagination: false,
            params: {
                id: 1
            }
        },
        getError: {
            url: 'https://demo0079948.mockable.io/posts',
            method: 'GET',
            scopeUpdate: 'post',
            localStorage: false,
            pagination: false,
            params: {
                // none
            }
        },
    },

    /**
     * Returns rest objects and allows to extend the params property
     * @param {string} method
     * @param {object} options
     * @return {object}
     */
    endPoint: function(endPointMethod, options) {
        var defaults = this._rest[endPointMethod];
        $.extend(defaults.params, options);
        return defaults;
    }

}
```

Usage with restHttpComponent

```
restHttpComponent.request(postModel.endPoint('getPosts', {
   dateFrom: currentDate
}));
```

Can anyone see any negatives from doing this?

Comment: I won't do a code review for you, but in the principle, this works. I also do the same thing too, but I chain my methods to be able to call deeper end points, e.g. `service.one('topic', 1).one('subject', 33).get('comment', 3)`. FYI, there's also Restangular that does the same thing and is easy to use.

Comment: Looks good, thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

Just try to replace the api end point to

'https://demo0079948.mockable.io/posts/{id}'